# Frame inside a tkinter scrollbar is tiny -- not using available space

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I fix the view ?  it's comprossed and small.
It's because of scrollbar but can't know how to fix it.

Without scrollbar, it's ok.
But if I add it , that what I get...

Don't know how to fix it..

Can you help ?
[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
root.title('Notebook Demo')

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280)

frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
frame2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

text = tk.Text(frame1)
text.insert("end", "sss")
text.pack()

verscrlbar_frame1 = ttk.Scrollbar(text, orient="vertical")
horscrlbar_frame1 = ttk.Scrollbar(text, orient="horizontal")
text.config(xscrollcommand=horscrlbar_frame1.set, yscrollcommand=verscrlbar_frame1.set)

verscrlbar_frame1.config(command=text.yview)
horscrlbar_frame1.config(command=text.xview)

verscrlbar_frame1.pack(side='right', fill='y')
horscrlbar_frame1.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

notebook.add(frame1, text='General Information')
notebook.add(frame2, text='Profile')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: didn't you ask this question an hour ago?

Comment: Change `ttk.Scrollbar(text, ...)` to `ttk.Scrollbar(frame1, ...)`

Comment: First you don't need to call `frame1.pack(...)` and `frame2.pack(...)`. Second you need to change the parent of the two scrollbars from `text` to `frame1`.  Also you need to move `text.pack()` after packing the two scrollbars.

Comment: And I want a scrobar to text, not frame, if it with frame then If I scroll down then I will not see... @ TheLizzard  @acw1668

Comment: The scrollbars will only scroll the content of the text widget, not the frame.

Comment: Do you know how to adjust text/frame/notebook size to windows size @acw1668

Comment: `notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True, fill="both")` and `text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems with your code.

First, you add the text widget to a frame but you don't tell it to expand or shrink to fill the frame. Thus, it will be whatever its natural size is. You should configure `pack` to have the text widget fill the area that it has been allocated:

```
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Second, you are adding the scrollbars inside the text widget. When you call `pack` to add the scrollbars to the text widget, the text widget is going to shrink to fit the natural size of the scrollbars. Since you didn't force the widget to expand to fill its frame, it's going to shrink to the size that you're seeing.

As a general rule of thumb you should *not* put scrollbars inside a text widget. This behavior is one reason why you shouldn't do that, but another reason is that the scrollbars will overlay text at the edges of the widget.

You should make the scrollbars children of the frame, not the text widget. If you want them to appear as if they are inside the text widget, give the frame the same background color as the text widget and remove the text widget border.

```
verscrlbar_frame1 = ttk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical")
horscrlbar_frame1 = ttk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="horizontal")
```

You should probably also adjust the order in which you're packing them, though `grid` is a slightly better choice since the scrollbars won't overlap each other.

```
verscrlbar_frame1.pack(side='right', fill='y')
horscrlbar_frame1.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

There is a third problem with your code, though it's fairly harmless. You are calling `pack` on `frame1` and `frame2`, but then later adding `frame1` and `frame2` to the notebook. There's no point in calling `pack` on these widgets since you are adding them to the notebook.

Comment: Can you explain in the code what my fixes ? @Bryan Oakley

Comment: And I want a scrobar to text, not frame, if it with frame then If I scroll down then I will not see... @Bryan Oakley

Comment: @Alex: I didn't suggest scrolling the frame. The scrollbars don't have (and _shouldn't_) be _in_ the widget they are scrolling. Like I said, the scrollbars should be in the frame, not the text widget.